# Dynamic mysql query LIMIT not working

Tags: mysql

I'm creating the parameters to LIMIT a mysql query using PHP variables. I'm outputting the query to make sure it's right, and it is. However the results completely ignore the offset parameter. However if I manually type in the LIMIT, it works fine.

```
    $page_rows = 5; 
    $max = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."nslikethis_votes WHERE user_id = '$uid' AND active = 1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT " . $max;

    $rs = mysql_query($qry);

    $result = array();

    if($rs && $rows>0){
        while($lc = mysql_fetch_object($rs, "LikedContent")){
            $result[] = $lc;
        }       
    }

    return $result;
```

Outputting $qry gives me this whether I use $max or manually enter '5,5':

```
SELECT * FROM wp_nslikethis_votes WHERE user_id = '1' AND active = 1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5,5
```

Comment: I've also outputted the max variable and it looks fine, eg. '5,5'

Comment: Best guess is that either `$pagenum` is zero or undefined or `$page_rows` is zero or undefined. I'd suggest just stepping through the code with a debugger or outputting the `$qry` to a log/screen to figure this one out.

Comment: I said that I am outputting the $qry and it looks fine. Neither of those variables are undefined. The output of $qry looks the same for the dynamic creation and manual specification of the LIMIT. It makes no sense why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this for check:

```
$page_rows = "5";
$max = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 
$qry = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."nslikethis_votes WHERE user_id = '$uid' AND `active` = 1 ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT " . $max;

//check for variables in query like $wpdb->prefix, $uid: are they fine, and try adding tilded sign as above
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Should have mentioned that I set $page_rows = 5 above. Editing question now. So this didn't change anything. I'm also echoing the $max variable for debugging and it looks fine, eg. 5,5